# Adjusting the equation in two column IEEE style

Tags: equations, multline

I am trying to place an following equation in IEEE two column style but not getting it properly.

```
$
\begin{multline}
P_{out}^{s,lb} =\left[ \Phi \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{d=0}^{\infty} W_{-m-\frac{1}{2},0} (2\zeta) \frac{\left(\frac{1}{B}\right)^d}{\sigma^{2d+1}_{f_e}}W_{-d-\frac{1}{2},0} (2\Tilde{\zeta})\times \\ 
\left[\Theta \cdot  \Gamma(1+d)\Gamma(1+m)\right] - \left[\frac{\left(\frac{\gamma_s}{A\sigma^2_{f_r}}\right)^{-1-d}}{1+d}\right]  \Gamma(2+d+m)\\
\times \Upsilon\right]^L
\end{multline}
$
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please always provide a small test document not just a fragment. `multline` starts math mode so should not be inside `$`

Comment: Ok sir....sorry for that...will keep in mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to remove the `$` as display math environments should not be started in math mode.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{multline}
P_{out}^{s,lb} =\left[ \Phi \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{d=0}^{\infty} W_{-m-\frac{1}{2},0} (2\zeta) \frac{\left(\frac{1}{B}\right)^d}{\sigma^{2d+1}_{f_e}}W_{-d-\frac{1}{2},0} (2\Tilde{\zeta})\times \\ 
\left[\Theta \cdot  \Gamma(1+d)\Gamma(1+m)\right] - \left[\frac{\left(\frac{\gamma_s}{A\sigma^2_{f_r}}\right)^{-1-d}}{1+d}\right]  \Gamma(2+d+m)\\
\times \Upsilon\right]^L
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Produces the errors

```
! Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.10 \end{multline}
                   
? 
! Extra \right.
```

as you can not make a left-right pair span over a linebreak. use `\bigl` or `\Bigl` or whatever size looks best to you:

[image]

as a complete test document:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{multline}
P_{\mathrm{out}}^{s,lb} =\Bigl[ \Phi \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{d=0}^{\infty} W_{-m-\frac{1}{2},0} (2\zeta) \frac{\bigl(\frac{1}{B}\bigr)^d}{\sigma^{2d+1}_{f_e}}W_{-d-\frac{1}{2},0} (2\Tilde{\zeta})\times \\ 
\bigl[\Theta \cdot  \Gamma(1+d)\Gamma(1+m)\bigr] - \bigl[\frac{\bigl(\frac{\gamma_s}{A\sigma^2_{f_r}}\bigr)^{-1-d}}{1+d}\bigr]  \Gamma(2+d+m)\\
\times \Upsilon\Bigr]^L
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir....